# php for loop breaking site layout

Tags: php, css

This is my old code

```
$xml .=  '<select style="width:80%;margin-bottom:10px;" name="qty" class="input-text qty" id="qty">';
    foreach ($prices as $price) {
    $xml .= '<option value="'.$price['price_qty'].'">'.$price['price_qty'].' pieces - '.$price['formated_price'].' each</option>';
    }
$xml .= '</select>';
```

I replaced that with this code

```
$xml .=  '<select style="width:80%;margin-bottom:10px;" name="qty" class="input-text qty" id="qty">';
    for ($i=1;$i<=100;$i++) {
    $xml .= '<option value="'.$i.'">'.$i.'</option>';
    }
$xml .= '</select>';
```

For some reason for loop breaking my grid layout. Can someone tell me whats wrong with my code?

Comment: Have you inspected the ouput HTML-code?

Comment: new code looks correct as old one was. How was that broken your layout ?

Comment: @CommuSoft Yes I did. I couldn't find any bug.

Comment: @Giri Would you post the output HTML, please? Maybe, we can find a bug.

Comment: are you sure its a php issue as opposed to newly added CSS issue? do you have a screenshot or a link to the broken view?

Comment: This looks like a CSS issue. specifically for class .item, .first, im assuming its should be 4 columns? When i replace the class of the <li class="item first"> with class="item last" ever 4 items it works as expected.

Comment: @Dave yes its 4 columns.But I replaced only foreach loop with for loop. I just switched back to foreach loop. Please refresh the page. As you can see it looks correct now.

Comment: Removed my last comment to correct a minor typo. are you sure you didn't make any additional adjustments to any code other than the foreach loop?

Comment: @Dave Yes i'm pretty sure, I didn't make any other modifications. [Here is my full code](https://gist.github.com/mistergiri/6587023)

Comment: Try this, change your loop iterator from $i to $c for a quick second. i believe one of the for loops above is throwing this all off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the correct code : $i was overlapping with other parts of your script

```
$xml .=  '<select style="width:80%;margin-bottom:10px;" name="qty" class="input-text qty" id="qty">';
    for ($c=1;$c<=100;$c++) {
    $xml .= '<option value="'.$c.'">'.$c.'</option>';
    }
$xml .= '</select>';
```

Comment: no problem, hope it makes sense why you couldn't use $i. otherwise happy coding.